# Postfix relay email with two senders

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I'm using canonical_maps and smtp_header_checks to override the from-address of internally generated emails. This configuration works fine to perform this header update:

> echo "/^From:internal@test.*$/ REPLACE From: ${OVERRIDE_SENDER_NAME} outside@mydomain1.net" >> /etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks

However, I'd like to send the email arriving at postfix relay to the same recipient from 2 different senders i.e. the receiver will receive the same email from 2 different senders. For example:

1. Relay receives email with header from-address: internal@test.domain
2. Relay duplicates(?) the message and changes the from-address in the header. Recipient stays the same.
3. Recipient receives the same email from 2 different senders: outside@mydomain1.com & pretty@mydomain2.com

Is this possible to do in postfix?